# How to create scales on an dragon egg?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

### TLDR

How to add scales to an egg in Blender? They need to be correctly around the egg and change size depending on where on the egg they are (largest scales around the fat part of the egg and smallest on the top).

### Context

I am trying to learn blender for 3d printing, and I am having trouble figuring out how to add scales to an egg so that they wrap around the egg and change size depending on the position on the egg (largest scales on the widest part of the egg and smallest on the top of the egg).

I know how to model scales and how to group them. I tried this YouTube video about using point projection with geometry nodes

[Blender 3.3: Point Projection for Making Scales, Petals, Sequins, and the Like - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQdM7STo744)

But I am not able to correctly position the points of the scales (they need to point up and bend somewhat with the shape of the egg) and they also need to change size depending on where on the egg they are as described above.

I am guessing that using geometry nodes is the best way forward, but being fairly new to blender and 3d modeling, it’s not easy to figure out.

This is an example of what I would like to achieve in the end

[image: dragon egg]

Comment: Can you show your best result? Did you try the Tissue add-on?

Answer (score 5):

If you feel comfortable with sculpting you could use [this method](https://youtube.com/watch?v=RNu1wrmYUIQ) explained by blender 52. You need to open the *Symmetry* panel and choose a number of *Radial Z* repetition (keep X symmetry selected if needed). You could also use a b&w texture as pattern (see the Blender Secrets tuto [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO0hd8S-ATI)):

[image]

[image]

Or create the pattern, mirror and array it:

[image]

Use the *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode, 360° on Z) to make it circular:

[image]

Duplicate to keep a non-destructive version, edit with the *Proportional Editing* activated:

[image]

Comment: In combination with the upcoming VDM brushes, sculpting something like this would take just a minute or two. Great answer.

Comment: Oh ok I haven't heard about these brushes

Comment: I think they'll be introduced in the next release (3.5), you can try them in the beta but here you can see the Z-Brush equivalent tool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4zg_95mbEI

Comment: wow that's impressive, thanks